# Wrong saving/allocation/setting of variables

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, local-variables

I have a problem with my code and I do not find the mistake, must be something trivial.

```
// This list is filled with Objects of Matcher
ArrayList<Matcher > fullListForBundle = new ArrayList<>();

// making a new ArrayList
ArrayList<Matcher> bundlelist = new ArrayList<>();

// making a new object
Matcher currentBundle = new Matcher();

// Searching trough an Arraylist of Objects.
for (Matcher current : stockDataCompleteWithBundle)
{
    // Get an Identifier
    String han = current.getThirdColumn();
    // Search through an other list to match identifier
    for (int i = 0; i < fullListForBundle.size(); i++)
    {
        // If identifier matches then do:
        if (fullListForBundle.get(i).getFifteenthColumn().equals(han))
        {
            // I want to get the right object and save it in currentBundle
            currentBundle = fullListForBundle.get(i);

            // !!! Here begins my problem !!!

            // Then I want to change two Strings in that particular Object
            currentBundle.setFirstColumn(current.getFirstColumn());
            currentBundle.setThirteenthColumn(current.getSecondColumn());

            // And add that object to a new Arraylist
            bundlelist.add(currentBundle);
            }

        }
    }
```

My Problem is: By setting the firstColumn and thirteenthColumn, the data in the fullListBundle.get(i) Object is changed and not the currentBundle Object. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do,

```
currentBundle = fullListForBundle.get(i);
```

Both `currentBundle` and `fullListForBundle.get(i)` referred to the same object in the heap. You should see the same results with both. If you just want the `currentBundle` to have your changes try,

```
 currentBundle = fullListForBundle.get(i).clone();
```

EDIT : `Object.clone()` method has `protected` access, meaning it's visible to sub-classes and classes in the same package.

It's good to have a copy constructor for manually copying the object.

```
/**
    Deep copy all the information from other to this
*/
public Matcher(Matcher other) {
   this.id = other.id;
}
```

[Read `Why a copy constructor by Josh Bloch ?`](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Comment: If `Matcher` is `java.util.regex.Matcher`, then this suggestion will not work, since Matcher doesn't implement `Cloneable`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException `currentBundle` is a `Matche` . And `currentBundle` has a method called `setFirstColumn`. So it is not `java.util.regex.Matcher`. And very class has Object as a superclass. `Object` class has a `clone` method. So  `java.util.regex.Matcher` will have a `clone` method also.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException `Matcher` is my own class with a different name than Matcher (I just wanted to change my class name to something generic).
@prime Anyhow: `currentBundle = fullListForBundle.get(i).clone();` does not work, because "The method clone() from the type Object is not visible"

Comment: @akBen then you will need to either implement a `clone()` method yourself, or, [better still, write a copy constructor](https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) and then do `currentBundle = new Matcher(fullListForBundle.get(i));`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks. I wrote a copy constructor. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the same object. you need to get a cloned object and do changes.

```
currentBundle = fullListForBundle.get(i).clone()
```

Comment: I tried cloning my list, but the references won´t be cloned and I get the same result as before.